# How to deal with OverflowError when you modify exif data for images?

Tags: python

Inside a loop the code successfully modifies exif data for jpeg images,

```
...  
with open(f"{old_source_path}{item.path}", "rb") as im_file:
    imexif = Image2(im_file)
    # Description
    imexif.copyright = "Copyright 2023 somebody. All Rights Reserved."
    # GPS
    imexif.gps_latitude = decdeg2dms(item.latitude)
    imexif.gps_longitude = decdeg2dms(item.longitude)
    imexif.gps_altitude = item.altitude
...
```

but sometimes there are errors which I seem not be able to put in a try block:

```
 ...\backend\venv\Lib\site-packages\plum\buffer.py", line 53, in unpack_and_dump
    raise UnpackError(dump, exc) from exc
plum.exceptions.UnpackError:

+--------+------------+-------+-------+------------------------+
| Offset | Access     | Value | Bytes | Format                 |
+--------+------------+-------+-------+------------------------+
|        |            |       |       | TiffHeader (Structure) |
| 0      | byte_order | 22166 | 56 96 | tiff_byte_order        |
+--------+------------+-------+-------+------------------------+

ValueError occurred during unpack operation:

22166 is not a valid TiffByteOrder
```

There are more such errors from the plum package such as OverflowError. How to deal with these?

Comment: You have to find first mention of your code in exception message and wrap it to try-except block. Or show here full exception message.

Comment: Maybe the file that you try to open is not actually a JPG file, or it is a JPG file with a non-standard header, see https://gitlab.com/TNThieding/exif/-/issues/49 and https://gitlab.com/TNThieding/exif/-/issues/36 for more information (but without a solution unfortunately).

Answer (score 0):

I am experiencing the same error as @ML Rozendale.  I am opening a valid JPG file and trying this command: `image.gps_latitude = (40, 30, 46.8235)` in a try-except block, and this is the full exception message:

```
<class 'plum.exceptions.PackError'>

+--------+-------+-------+--------+
| Offset | Value | Bytes | Format |
+--------+-------+-------+--------+
|        | 65570 |       | uint16 |
+--------+-------+-------+--------+

OverflowError occurred during pack operation:

int too big to convert
```